# using NestWhile to manipulate a list with certain condition

Tags: function, wolfram-mathematica, nested-loops, repeat, list-manipulation

Two initial number {20,39}; first one over 2 and second one over 3 in iteration. If the first element less than 4, then loop break and give out the latest list. The iteration no more than 7. If after run 7 iterations, first element still more than 4, then output the latest list.

```
NestWhile[{#[[1]]/2, #[[2]]/3} &, {20, 39}, (Print[##, #[[1]]]; #[[1]] < 4) &, 1, 7]
```

I thought it will give me `{5/2, 13/9}`; but, its give me `{20, 39}`. Looks the condition is not work... I don't understand how to manipulate a list by Nestwhile...

Comment: you test is `20<4` on first pass so it doesnt run at all.

Comment: suspect `#[[1]]>=4` is what you want